# windows 10 stopped being detected in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've used my pc setup for around 2 years with no problems until today. I suppose something happened to my Windows 10 Microsoft Reserved Partition and I no longer see windows 10 in grub menu.

Here's `boot-repair` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26321154/

And here's `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223,6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6FD155B8-D20F-463D-8116-B6493AAA06AD

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1159168 381104321 379945154 181,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  381106176 382840831   1734656   847M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  382842880 468860927  86018048    41G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3dc2dafb

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2           206848  839272447  839065600 400,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        839272448 2517198847 1677926400 800,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       2517200894 3907028991 1389828098 662,7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       2517200896 3456466943  939266048 447,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6       3702228992 3878008288  175779297  83,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       3878010880 3907028991   29018112  13,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb8       3456468992 3702226943  245757952 117,2G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

So the situation is kinda complicated here, because I have a lot of filesystems spread around 2 HDDs, so let me explain:

`/dev/sda` stands for my SSD drive. `sda6` is ubuntu 16.04 that I currently use - it works. `sda3` is `windows 10 MBR` I believe, which is not visible in grub.

`/dev/sdb` is my old hard drive. It got ubuntu 14.04 as well as windows 7 installed... just because I'm lazy and never got rid of them. So `dev/sdb` also had grub installed.

Here are my current grub options on (sda6):

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic (upstart)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic (upstart)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-63-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-63-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-62-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-62-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (on /dev/sdb6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb6)
```

And here options from old `Ubuntu 14.04 on sdb`:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-63-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-63-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-62-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic (upstart) (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic (upstart) (on /dev/sda6)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda6)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdc1)
```

**So it seems like GRUB is started from `sdb` as those options I actually see on system boot, although the sda drive is set as primary boot option in EFI BIOS... after disconnecting `sdb` hdd I don't see grub menu and nothing boots up**

Any ideas how to bring back my windows 10?

Comment: Did you recheck the Windows settings, like the power options to hibernate instead of shutdown?  Those sometimes get reset when Windows updates.  You should always be able to use the EFI menu, (some function key at power-up), to select Windows and skip grub completely.

Comment: @ubfan1 how can I select windows from EFI menu? I'm only able to select the boot drive, which is set to my SSD drive.

Comment: Also, booting from sda fails right now (after disconnecting sdb I get a message: `select a proper boot device and reboot`) and fallbacks to sdb.  My mobo is asrock p67 pro3.

Comment: You have a BIOS boot grub & 14.04 install in a MBR(msdos) sdb drive. But you have an UEFI install of 16.04 in sda6. And you booted live installed to run Boot-Repair in old BIOS/MBR, better to boot it in UEFI mode. And once you change to UEFI, best to have all installs UEFI on gpt partitioned drives. Your Windows BIOS boot loader in gpt's protective MBR on gpt drive will never work as Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt drives. You may need to turn UEFI on or CSM/BIOS/Legacy off. Some systems call it "Windows" and "Other" where Other is Secure boot off.